# scrap image with request header on beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have code for scrap image:

```
import requests, base64
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


baseurl = "https://www.google.com/search?q=cat&sxsrf=APq-WBuyx07rsOeGlVQpTsxLt262WbhlfA:1650636332756&source=lnms&tbm=shop&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjQr5HC66f3AhXxxzgGHejKC9sQ_AUoAXoECAIQAw&biw=1920&bih=937&dpr=1"
headers = {"User-Agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:99.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/99.0"}

r_images = requests.get(url=baseurl, headers=headers)


soup_for_image = BeautifulSoup(r_images.text, 'html.parser') 
#find product images
productimages = [] 
product_images = soup_for_image.findAll('img')
for item in product_images:
    # print(item['src'])
    if "data:image/svg+xml" not in item['src']:
        productimages.append(item.get('src'))
print(productimages)
```

It will be fine if there is no header but, if I use request header, the result will be base64 image. So is there any way that I can scrap the image with the request headers?

Comment: You want to put some headers to get only data:image/svg+xml images from google search?

Comment: no, I wanna use headers, because I wanna to get price, name and link which need request headers, But if I use that the url_image changed to base64. If I request without headers I cannot scrap price,name and the link(to product)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add cookie CONSENT and it works.
Maybe some selectors can change in the future.

```
import requests, base64
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

baseurl = "https://www.google.com/search?q=cat&sxsrf=APq-WBuyx07rsOeGlVQpTsxLt262WbhlfA:1650636332756&source=lnms&tbm=shop&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjQr5HC66f3AhXxxzgGHejKC9sQ_AUoAXoECAIQAw&biw=1920&bih=937&dpr=1"
headers = {"cookie": "CONSENT=YES+cb.20230531-04-p0.en+FX+908"}
result = requests.get(url=baseurl, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(result.text, 'html.parser')
allProducts = soup.findAll(class_="u30d4")
number = 0
for product in allProducts:
    name = product.find(class_="rgHvZc")
    if name is not None:
        number += 1
        print("Product number %d:" % number)
        print("Name : " + name.text)
        productLink = product.find('a')
        print("Link: " + productLink["href"][7:])
        img = product.find('img')
        print("Image: " + img["src"])
        price = product.find(class_="HRLxBb")
        print("Price " + price.text)
```

I hope I have been able to help you.

Comment: its indeed solved my problem

Comment: could you gimme reference for me to learn more?

Comment: the code above works perfectly but i have some problem, the image that has scrapped is on bad resolution, could you give a reference for better quality image according to code above.